# How purchase and consume Individual coins?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have a packs of coins that the user can buy. For example:

- 50 coins
- 200 coins
- 500 coins

If user buy 50 coins, user can spend in game coins one by one.

**Is there any way for Google to take care of the inventory management?**, for example, a way for is saved in the Google server that if the user has 50 coins and spends 10 he has 40 coins in inventory.

In case that this is not possible, I would have to manage the coin inventory myself. In local device I can not do it because I want them to be associated with an account of user. Therefore I can only manage the coins in my game server.

I consider it quite dangerous to do this implementation on my own. For example, the user buys a pack, I call my server server to increase the number of coins of that user account. My server answers "OK" because he added the coins. Then in the application I use consume the pack of coins so that there is evidence that they have been added to your account correctly.

But if there is a game server connection error in the response the application would not consume them and the user could add them to the inventory again, this is only an example of problem but with different ways of implementing it that I have thought some possible failures happen.

**Is there an example or scheme implemented to manage the coins of a user with a inventory in "game server"?**

Additional information: My server is java with api rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

1. When you make a purchase, send the purchase token to your server (just like you wrote above).
2. Your server should use the [Google Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) to confirm this is a real purchase. If it is, adds the coins to the database and *marks the purchase as redeemed*. It responds with the number of coins the user now has so that the app can display it.

About the problem of step (2) failing:
What you can do is to retrieve the purchases of the user when the app starts using the [In-App billing library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) and send a request to the server for those that had failed earlier. Of course, you'll need some kind of local database (or use shared preferences) to store those that failed and those that were redeemed successfully.